# Adempiere - Table not found AD_System

Tags: postgresql, adempiere

This question is for those who have experience with Adempiere ERP.

when logging in, I get the error table ad_system is not found. connecting to Postgresql I can see the database along with the table name. not sure why it says so. anyone else experienced the same issue?

my Postgres user does have superuser permissions

[error message on login]

[image: 1]

Comment: Its likely that there is an issue in the setup.  When you RUN_Setup, do all the tests pass?

Comment: I get this error running RUN_Setup.   Version 393

Answer (score 0):

Try to query the database to see if it has data or if it's empty, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM AD_System
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM C_BPartner
```

That error usually appears when you do a bad DB restoration and the DB Tables are empty.